# Authenticate User from within rails /lib module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, module, tcp

I want to authenticate Users when they try to fire up a TCP connection in my Rails app. Here's the current code I have, it's very simplistic but should give you an idea of what I want to do.

#### TcpServer.rb

```
module TcpServer
  
  def receive_data(data)
    (@buf ||= '') << data
    if line = @buf.slice!(/(.+)\r?\n/)
      commands = data.split(";")
      case commands[0]
      when /start/i
        if !User.authenticate(commands[1],commands[2])
          close_connection
          puts "Subscription invalid."
        else
          put "Subscription validated."
        end
      end
    end
  end
  
EventMachine::run do
  host = "localhost"
  port = "5587"
  EventMachine::start_server host, port, TcpServer
  puts "TcpServer started @ #{host}:#{port}"
end
  
end
```

What do I need to require or include in order to access my User model from that module? Or is this just a completely incorrect way to do it? If so, what do you suggest?

The issue is I wasn't running it with Rails.

I was running it with:

```
ruby lib/TcpServer.rb
```

rather than:

```
script/runner lib/TcpServer.rb
```

No includes or requires needed, Rails did it automagically.

Comment: have you tried to put `require 'user.rb'`? Or maybe try to pass `user` like a parameter in `receive_data`?

Comment: You can access models from files in /lib folder atleast in Rails 2.3.5..not sure about Rails 3..

Comment: Can or can't? I've tried the first Kishie, doesn't do it. The latter wouldn't be possible with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app/models/*.rb')).each { |file| require file }
```

The above will get all models loaded if you need them (you can just add 'user.rb' to the statement if needed, in the comment above you may need to specify the path and not include the ".rb" part -> "require 'user'").

You should make a decision as to whether you think this type of integration server should be part of the running Rails app or potentially another "application" that is part of the same code base.  You could keep the core internals here and start your EM server with a custom rake task and load the Rails env through that rake task.

```
namespace :tcp do  
  task :start, :needs => :environment do
    # server load and start here
  end
end
```

If I am going to open a new means of execution then I prefer to keep these running in separate processes to keep any errors from causing both to go down together.  (I would look at Resque jobs/workers as a good example of how to keep code in the same Rails app without forcing them to run in the same process)